# Set EnvironmentName at publish time and use at runtime

Tags: c#, environment-variables, .net-6.0

Using c# .net6,
how can I set the EnvironmentName at compilation or publish time and access it at run time? Is this possible? I tried passing as a publish parameter
`dotnet publish -p:EnvironmentName=Development`
but it is not persisted to runtime.
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvironmentName")`
returns null at run time

I also tried to pass EnvironmentName in through publish profile with no success.

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` reads information from environment variables. `dotnet publish` does not set environment variables at some possibly unknown to it target machine.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Usually it is not an optimal solution which will require rebuilding project for every environment.

Comment: It is an application that is added into excel. I do not have environments as such. I want it to use the correct appsettings.json depending on which version the users downloads. so that the test and uat settings can be different than the production application.

At run time, where can I read the environment name that was set at publish time? Is it only used by msbuild and lost after publish?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET applications, `IWebHostEnvironment` provide the environment name it via `EnvironmentName` property.

You could use it via dependency injection:

```cs
public class TestController : ControllerBase {
    
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public ConfigController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetEnvironmentName() {
        return _environment.EnvironmentName;
    }
}
```

Or in strartup code via `builder.Environment.EnvironmentName` or `app.Environment.EnvironmentName`.